# How to answer batch file

Tags: networking, command-line, permissions, batch, batch-file

I lost my administrator right's in recovery. I learned of the super administrator surfing the net and got access using command line. I got a reply :`The syntax of this command is:` and then it list's

```
NET USER [user password  : * ] [options] ] [/DOMAIN] 
username {password : * } / [options] [DOMAIN] 
username [/DELETE] [/DOMAIN] 
username [/TIMES: { times : ] ALL } 
username [/ACTIVE : {YES : NO }
```

What is c: asking ? and how do I answer ?

Comment: I've voted to approve the suggested edit from a helpful person, that at least fixes the markup.  I wanted to build on that, but it seems impossible to figure out what the questioner is actually asking here.  What batch file?  Who is this super administrator?  What were you recovering from and why is that at all relevant?  [Please follow the standard litany](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).

Comment: What do you mean by c: in your last sentence, or do you mean what does the entire message mean that followed a C: prompt on the command line?  If the latter is the case, the message is a user-manual for the command, showing you how to format the command for its different uses.  It probably appeared because your command did not precisely follow the required syntax for the usage you tried.  For someone to help, please edit your question to add the command line you tried to use.

Answer (score -2):

1. Boot CD Windows Vista/7/8 and wait language choice dialog
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> - run `cmd`
3. Run `notepad` and open file, to view logical disk, and find disk name with OS.or search disk name use comand:

   ```
   bcdedit /enum| find /I "os"
   ```
4. go to system32 directory

   ```
   cd /d <OS disk name>:\W*\s*32
   ```
5. rename

   ```
   ren Utilman.exe *2.*
   ```
6. replace Utilman.exe

   ```
   copy cmd.exe Utilman.exe
   ```
7. Reboot, and boot at HDD
8. In Logon screen click on the <kbd>Ease of Access Center</kbd> icon. - It run `cmd` at `System` right - max right at OS.
9. In `cmd`, create user:

   ```
   net user /add <UserName> <Password>
   ```
10. view local group:

    ```
    net localgroup
    ```
11. add a user to administrators group:

    ```
    net localgroup Administrators /add <UserName>
    ```
12. Reboot and logon at  and  and run `cmd` as administrator
13. Restore Utilman.exe

    ```
    del Utilman.exe *2.*
    ```

and

```
ren Utilman2.exe Utilman.exe
```

14. Set administrator grop and user as owner disk C:

    ```
    cd \
    ```

and

```
TAKEOWN /F C:\ /R /A /D Y
```

15. Reset NTFS security settings:

    ```
    icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET
    ```
16. Restore security settings:

    ```
    secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose
    ```
17. Reboot