# Reset Windows 7 Admin Password

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I am having an issue.  I have a machine that has 2 users, the admin user and another user which seems to have basically no permissions to do anything.  I do not know the admin password and every time I try to do anything form the other user account it prompts me for that admin user password. I have tried a number of methods to reset the password from changing UAC, various 3rd party windows password reset tools, and several other suggestions I found but when I try to do anything including creating a bootable image I get prompted for the admin password.  There are files that are very important in the admin users documents that I need but I can't seem to find a way to get them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This post is not a duplicate, the methods suggested in the "duplicate" post here "[What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-7-password)" do not solve my issue.  When I try to run those executable I am prompted for the admin user's credentials.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/871978/how-to-answer-batch-file/872010#872010 or http://superuser.com/questions/552189/password-reset-programs-only-find-passwords-from-one-os-on-a-dual-boot-system/552201#552201

Comment: If your being asked for a password if your booting to a bootable disk that isn't a windows password being requested the other prompts obviously are.  This PC on a domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound Whence then know the password one of a user ?))

Comment: @STTR - What???

Comment: If you can't even write to a CD from your computer, you may need to do that from another machine.  (Do you have any friends who have computers?)

Comment: @Scott I tried the methods suggested no luck, when I attempt to run those executables I get prompted for a password.

Comment: @Scott the machine is a friends machine and I have 2 machines of my own that both run Windows 8.1 the problem there being I don't think I can create a bootable Windows 7 cd or iso from a Windows 8.1 machine can I??

Comment: @Scott's comment (the URL to the answer!) will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [Offline NT Password Changer](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) included in the [Hiren Boot](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) package.
I haven't checked it though.

*Official Documentation* reads:

> 1. This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has a valid
>      local account on your Windows system.
> 2. Supports all Windows from NT3.5 to Win8.1, also 64 bit and also the Server versions (like 2003, 2008, 2012)
> 3. You do not need to know the old password to set a new one.
> 4. Will detect and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!

Comment: yes, I get prompted for the admin credentials

Answer (score -2):

open command line  type

> net user

to find out the two users

then type for example username of the administrator

> net user jone *

**Type a password for the user: will prompt twice.**

it should reset the  password for the Admin account

Comment: He doesn't have access to an `Administrator` user.  So these commands will prompt him for the password he is trying to change.

Comment: @Ramhound is correct, when I even attempt to run a command prompt as administrator I get prompted for the admin credentials.