# Removed my user from administrator group by mistake?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am running Windows 7. I just removed my user from administrator group by mistake. Then I added some password for main administrator user. When I logged-off from my user and try to login using main administrator user, it says administrator user is disabled. When I login again from my user account it says I don't have administrative rights. How to fix this?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/871978/how-to-answer-batch-file run `mmc` > `Local User and Group` snap-in > add Administrator group. Or at `cmd` run `net localgroup Administrators /add <UserName>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart computer and [boot in to Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/zh-hk/windows/start-computer-safe-mode), then you will be able to login with build-in administrator account, put back your user account as administrators group, restart computer back to Normal Mode and you will be able to login with your own account with admin right.